# sscanf handles maximal unsigned integer value differently than assignment does

Tags: c, scanf, integer-overflow, twos-complement

Consider the following code :

```
main()
{
  int assigned = 4294967295;     // Max unsigned integer value on 32-bits arch

  char input[] = "4294967295";
  int sscanned;


  unsigned int result = sscanf(input, "%d", &sscanned);
  printf ("scanned %u elements : %d\n
          "Assigned j = %d\n", 
          result, sscanned, assigned);

  return 0;
}
```

When compiled for 32-bits arch (with compilation command: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -pedantic -m32 test_sscanf.c -o test_sscanf32`), it spits out an expectable warning about "*overflow in conversion from ‘long long int’ to ‘int’ changes value from ‘4294967295’ to ‘-1’ [-Woverflow]*".

Now seeing the result :

```
> ./test_sscanf32 
scanned 1 elements : 2147483647
Assigned j = -1
```

While the `assigned` value has rightfully been converted into the maximal negative signed integer value, through two's complement representation (-1 = ***-2^31 + 2^30 + ... + 2^0***), the `scanned` value on the other hand has apparently got its MSB dismissed which caused it to shrink to the value 2147483647 = ***2^31 - 1***.

So my question is : what does justify such a difference in the treatment of the *maximum n-bits integer value* on an *n-bits machine* (knowing that on a 64-bits arch, the same behavior occurs) ?
Is a programmer not rightfully entitled to expect that `sscanf` would treat the value the same way an assignment does, on a given architecture ?

Comment: Use `%u` to read an unsigned int.

Comment: @wildplasser I am aware of that. But it's not my question ! My question pertains to why `sscanf` handles *signed maximal integer value* by casting away its MSB, while an assignment simply converts it with two's complement ?

Comment: The assignment is done by the compiler; the scanning is done by a library routine. They may use different algorithms to derive the value from the ascii characters. As wildplasser says, use %u to read unsigned; otherwise the result is not defined.

Comment: ...for example, the compiler itself is 64 bits and truncates the value but the run-time library routine is 32 bits and overflows.

Comment: Note: the argument to sscanf() is *only* a pointer. You could hand it a pointer to a float and still complain that the observed behaviour is not what you expect.

Comment: "... to why sscanf handles signed maximal integer value by casting away its MSB".  This is not what happened.  Try `char input[] = "4294967290";`  (last digit 0 not 5).  I suspect the result will still be `2147483647`.  Review `strtol()` for insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting an integer value to `int` by cast or assignment, when the value is not representable by `int` but is representable by some supported type with a larger range, produces an implementation-defined value in the `int` ([C11 §6.3.1.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3)).  Almost all implementations nowadays define this conversion such that `int x = UINT_MAX;` sets x to −1.  The only exception I am aware of is Unisys (née Burroughs) mainframes, which still use ones-complement representation for negative numbers.

By contrast, all of the `scanf` functions have *undefined* behavior upon reading a number which is outside of the representable range for the type of the variable the number will be written to ([C11 §7.21.6.2p10](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p10)).  That means, not only can you *not* count on it to do the same thing that integer conversion does, you can't count on it to do anything constructive at all, and the compiler would in fact be entitled to generate machine code that makes demons fly out of your nose.

It is my considered opinion that 7.21.6.2p10 is a defect in the standard, but since I consider the `scanf` family unfit for purpose *anyway* (this is only one of many problems with them), I can't be bothered to file a DR.  Use the `strto*` functions instead.  They have well-defined and documented overflow behavior.

Comment: @programmersn I pretty much have this particular rant memorized.  It comes up a lot, here and elsewhere.

Comment: @chux Thanks, I always forget that decimal literals don't follow the same type determination rules as hex literals.  Please see what you think of the revised text.

Comment: Good - UV.  Curious this answer discusses the ID behavior of assignment (which can include a "signal is raised") as discounted as a large concern and -1 is expected yet the UB of `scanf()` is painted bad quite broadly when it is certain code simply acted like `strtol()` would and assigned `INT_MAX`. IMO, The IDB vs UB is only marginal better and your advice to use `strto*()` is the best approach.

Comment: @chux It's a fair point. The reason I deprecate `scanf` a lot more than the i-d integer conversion overflow behavior is I know a lot more about what can be expected from the i-d integer conversion overflow on real implementations than what can be expected from `scanf` on real implementations.  Yes, OP's implementation seems to have called `strtol`, but I don't personally know that that can be relied on cross-platform.  Also I get really nervous nowadays about compilers drawing optimization inferences from UB, even inside library functions.

Comment: True  "nervous nowadays about compilers drawing optimization inferences from UB" is a real concern.  With IDB, at least the compiler maker needs to state the behavior, and that begets a history for them making future changes less capricious.

Answer (score 2):

Using the wrong format specifier for `scanf` invokes [undefined behavior](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), so the result doesn't have to make sense.

For example, running the same code on my machine gives the following results:

```
scanned 1 elements : -1
Assigned j = -1
```

So use `%u` instead of `%d`.

Comment: In OP's sample code, the format specifier does match the type of the variable being written; it's the value that's out of range (which is still UB, but under a different rule).